# wso2ei-6.4.0 and XSLT 3.0 support

Tags: xslt, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, xslt-3.0, wso2-esb

I am planning to used XSL version 3.0 for my WSO2 EI application. Because, I need to map JSON to JSON and JSON to XML in my application. Currently I have try with version 2.0. Please refer following code for current implementation.

I need to know how change this version and which jar required in WSO2EI for xsl version 3.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:param name="STATIC_BODY_PARAM"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="/availabilityRequest">

        <availabilityRequest>
            <control>
                <userName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="control/userName" />
                </userName>
                <passWord>
                    <xsl:value-of select="control/passWord" />
                </passWord>
            </control>
             ....................
        </availabilityRequest>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I used version as 3.0, I got following error message. I have added your further reference.

```
ERROR - XSLTMediator Error creating XSLT transformer using : Value {name ='null', expression =fn:concat('gov:repository/transformation/',$ctx:uri.var.travel_type,'_',$ctx:uri.var.activity,'_',$ctx:uri.var.supplier_id,'_in.xslt')}
net.sf.saxon.trans.LicenseException: Requested feature (XSLT 3.0) requires Saxon-PE
    at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.checkLicensedFeature(Configuration.java:584)
    at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.setStylesheetDocument(PreparedStylesheet.java:331)
    at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.prepare(PreparedStylesheet.java:207)
    at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:132)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator.createTemplate(XSLTMediator.java:467)
```

Comment: I have tried with following link steps. Still not working as expected. Link:- https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2826

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything specifically about WSO2EI, but it appears (from your link) that it is currently running with some older version of Saxon-HE.

Simply substituting the Saxon 9.9 JAR file for the one that is distributed with the product may work, or it may not. It's very likely to work, but it's possible that the stylesheets, or the calling application, depend on something in Saxon that has changed.

If you've tried something, there's no point telling us it doesn't work. You need to tell us exactly how it failed.

You should try running a stylesheet that outputs the value of `system-property('xsl:product-version')` so you have positive confirmation of which Saxon version is being picked up.

You don't need to make any changes to your stylesheets to use XSLT 3.0 features, but it's a good idea to change the version attribute to `version="3.0"` for documentation reasons.

Comment: This issue may happen due to following jar (saxon.he_9.4.0.wso2v1.jar). WSO2 EI used Home edition version. Need to resolved this.  I got this information from following link. http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-replace-saxonhe940wso2v1jar-in.html

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed above problem using following information.

- I got the 30 trail license key with registering http://www.saxonica.com/download/download.xml (saxon-license.lic) and it put into /wso2ei-6.4.0/ folder
- Remove this jar (saxon.he_9.4.0.wso2v1.jar) on following location. (/wso2ei-6.4.0/wso2/components/plugins)
- Also put this jar (saxon9ee.jar) http://www.saxonica.com/download/SaxonEE9-4-0-6J.zip into /wso2ei-6.4.0/lib location
- Restart the wso2ei-6.4.0 server
- Now xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" working without any issue.

I have got those details from following link. Many thanks for that.
http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-replace-saxonhe940wso2v1jar-in.html

Comment: Saxon 9.8 and 9.9 HE support XSLT 3 as specified as a W3C recommendation in 2017. Whether they work within your particular environment I don't know. Saxon 9.4 EE was released much before XSLT 3 was standardized so depending on your needs it might not implement features of the standard or implement them in a different way then standardized in 2017.